# Flutter and IOS app development and testing before release

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-developer

I have a Flutter app for which I have released an Android version on Play Store. Now I am planning to work on IOS part and release it too. However I need to fix and test the IOS part like notifications, Facebook and Google login, etc.

My question is, do I need to **register and pay** to the Apple developer program in order to **get the Authentication Key to test push notification**?

Like when I go to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs it asks to go Apple Developer account in order to get the Authentication key. When I go to the [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) and login, there is no option to download the Authentication key.

Regards

Comment: Yes, you need a paid Apple Developer Account to be able to test push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot comment yet.

Well if you're looking to only work on your app that's fine, although I don't know that exactly do you mean by "However I need to fix and test the IOS part like notifications, Facebook and Google login, etc.". But you can build and use a free Apple developer account and upload your app on a single iPhone no problem. But you do have to have Mac and Xcode. If you're using Windows or any other OS that is not from Apple you're out of luck.

Comment: I have Mac machine. I want to know, if I want to test all my app features especially notification do I have to have paid developer account?